# How to specify assembly information when compiling code at runtime with cs-script library?

Tags: c#, assemblyversions, cs-script

I am creating an assembly at runtime with CSScriptLibrary. 
Everything works fine, but my resulting assembly does not have the required assembly information.

If I include the assembly information attributes (found in AssemblyInfo.cs in every C# project) in the code-string the compilation fails with "duplicate attribute error".

Here is the code with which I create my assembly:

```
try
{                
      compiledResultAssembly = CSScriptLibrary.CSScript.LoadCode(code, assemblyReferences.ToArray());                
}
catch(Exception ex)
{ }
```

How do I specify the assembly version so that the "compiledResultAssembly" is not in version 0.0.0.0?

The version of CSScriptLibrary is 3.11.1.0.

Thanks in advance

---

**Edit 08.07.2019**

I found the solution. The CSScriptLibrary injects a AssemblyDescription attribute at some point, which causes the "duplicate attribute" error.

To specify assembly version information simply use the following setup of you scriptcode:

```
using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
// all your usings

[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.2.3.4")]
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("1.2.3.4")]

namespace YourNamespace
{
    // your code here
}
```

Note that the assembly attributes must be the first thing in your code an can not be placed  anywhere else.